# Setting homepage in package.json doesn't set PUBLIC_URL on build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package.json

Following the docs [here (Building for Relative Paths)](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#building-for-relative-paths), so setting homepage field in package.json doesn't set PUBLIC_URL during the build.

**Expected behavior**

`%PUBLIC_URL%` in `build/index.html` should be replaced with URL set in package.json's homepage field.

**package.json:**

```
"homepage": "https://example.com",
```

**build/index.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/static/js/main.ec7f8973.js">
```

**Actual behavior**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.ec7f8973.js">
```

`%PUBLIC_URL%` will be replaced with nothing.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2575

Comment: @AliAnkarali I already saw this. But that is not what I am looking for. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 8):

After setting homepage field in package.json the following message is displayed when you generate your build:

```
The project was built assuming it is hosted at https://example.com.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.
```

Which leads to your **Actual Behavior**.

I had the need to have a full URL for the meta tags such as *og:image* and *twitter:image:src*

As [Timer said](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2575#issuecomment-309790580): "Only the path of the URL is interpolated into %PUBLIC_URL%, unless if you explicitly use the PUBLIC_URL environment variable."

So I create an **.env** file at the root directory of my application adding a variable referencing the same url in package's homepage:

```
REACT_APP_BASE_URL=https://example.com
```

In index.html I replaced the %PUBLIC_URL% for the env variable:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="%REACT_APP_BASE_URL%/img/facebook_1200x630.jpg" />
```

And the result of the build:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/img/facebook_1200x630.jpg" />
```

Which I believe is what you need.

Comment: I didn't know you could use .env variables inside reactjs's public/index.html so THANKS FOR THAT

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario with the OP and this solution from Github worked for me: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2575#issuecomment-452295290

In your **environment variable file** (e.g., `.env`) simply set `PUBLIC_URL` as follows:

```
PUBLIC_URL="https://example.com"
```

This will yield the results as follows when you build your project:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://example.com/static/js/main.ec7f8973.js">
```

I have tested this using a production `.env.production` environment variable file so I do not know if assigning `PUBLIC_URL` in a generic `.env` will break local dev environment.